# Python: How to find the highest number in a column of data

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have csv and txt files and I want to analyze them and find the highest number in a specific column. For example I want to know the highest number (in all the rows) in column 5.  This what I have so far but I don't know how to figure out how to search a specific column.

```
`import csv

#opening csv
file = open("Scoring.csv","r")
csv = csv.reader(file) 
csv_1=[]

rows = []
for in_line in file:
    row = [float(each) for each in in_line.split()]
    rows.append(row)

file.close() # this'll happen at the end of the script / function / method anyhow

columns = zip(*rows)

for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    print "In row %s, Max = %s, Min = %s" % (index, max(row), min(row))

for index, column in enumerate(columns):
    print "In column %s, Max = %s, Min = %s" % (index, max(column), min(column))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following code

```
for index, column in enumerate(columns):
    print "In column %s, Max = %s, Min = %s" % (index, max(column), min(column))
```

you provided gives you correct answers and I understand you correctly, than getting min value (for example) from specific column should be easy enough, along the lines of min(columns[index_of_column]), for example:

```
min(columns[4])
```

For max value in column, replace min() with max(). And, remember, index_of_column is zero based (first column has index of 0, so 5th column would have an index of 4).

So, to get both min and max value, you would do:

```
print "In column %s, Max = %s, Min = %s" % (5, max(columns[4]), min(columns[4]))
```

Comment: how do I just do it for a specific column. Like say just column 5

Comment: So I understood you correctly. Added full example with printout of both min and max value.